# Массив создан из объектов одного класса С++

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, память, динамические-массивы

Написал код, но в строке

```
driver *a=new driver[nr]
```

выдает ошибку:

> undefined reference to driver::driver();

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
class driver
{
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    string categories;
    int salary, hours;


public:
    driver();
    ~driver()
    {
        std::cout<<"\nDestructor executed";
    }
    driver(driver const &cop)
    {
        name=cop.name;
        prename=cop.surname;
        categorii=cop.categories;
        salary=cop.salary;
        hours=cop.hours;
    }

driver(string n, string p, string c, int s, int h)
    {
      name.clear();
      surname.clear();
      categories.clear();
      salary=0;
      hours=0;
      init(n,p,c,s,h);
    }


void init(string n, string p, string c, int s, int h)
{
    name=n;
    surname=p;
    categories=c;
    salary=s;
    hours=h;
}

void reads()
{
    std::cout<<"\t\t Give information about driver:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t\t---------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"\tGive name: "; std::cin>>name;
    std::cout<<"\tGive surname: "; std::cin>>surname;
    std::cout<<"\tGive categories of driver license: "; std::cin>>categories;
    std::cout<<"\tHow much he is payd for hour: "; std::cin>>salary;
    std::cout<<"\tHow many hours did "<<n<<" "<<p<<" works? "; std::cin>>hours;

}

void print()
{
    std::cout<<name<<" "<<surname<<" ";
    std::cout<<"has categories "<<categories<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Salary per hour is "<<salary<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Driver had worked "<<hours<<" hours"<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Full payment is "<<salary*hours<<" $"<<endl;
}

};

int main()
{
 int nr,i;
 cout<<"Vvedite cislo voditeley:"; cin>>nr;
 driver a=new driver[nr];
 for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
 {
     a[i].reads();
     cout<<endl;
 }

 for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
 {
     a[i].print();
     cout<<endl;
 }
 delete[] a;


return 0;
}
```

Что не так в данном случае?

А также, как сделать чтобы `а` был динамическим массивом? Пробовал как в Си:

```
a=(driver*) malloc (nr*sizeof(driver))
```

, но не получается.

Comment: Надо реализовать функцию `driver::driver()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совершенно ясно ведь написано - нет `driver::driver();`. Вы объявили конструктор по умолчанию `driver();`, но тела-то не написали...

Еще у вас какие-то левые имена в

```
    prename=cop.surname;
    categorii=cop.categories;
```

В классе таких членов нет.

В `reads()` не объявлены `n` и `p`.

Ну, и в

```
driver a=new driver[nr];
```

у вас не хватает звездочки. Это - что касается синтаксиса.

Что вы понимаете под "динамическим массивом"? Если массив, выделенный в куче - то вы его уже получили (как только допишете конструктор по умолчанию). Через `malloc` категорически не советую - это просто выделение памяти, конструкторы/деструкторы не будут вызываться, и вообще, это не наш (C++) метод :)

Если массив, динамически меняющий свой размер во время выполнения - то руками это - судя по вашему коду - вам еще рановато, имеет смысл использовать `vector`.

Comment: `prename=cop.surname;
    categorii=cop.categories;`
  
    `n` и `p` в `reads()`
поправил в коде, допустил ошибку когда переводил чтобы было понятно.

Добавил `{}` к `driver()` и всё заработало. Ура!

 
Насчёт массива я хочу создать массив с данными char с "категориями" вод.прав для каждого водителя. Сейчас могу ввести только одну. Чтобы в `reads()` спрашивалось кол-во имеющихся категорий, а после этого создание массива с выделению памяти и запрос самих категории.

Comment: А! ну, поскольку категория - просто латинская буква, я бы просто держал строку категорий - у вас же это и так строка. Добавляйте к ней нужные буквы и не мучайтесь... Строка `string` и есть динамический массив элементов `char` :)

Comment: И еще - если ответ на вопрос устраивает - то вопрос закрывают, принимая ответ (птичка слева от него).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Закрываю

Comment: И еще - вы совершенно напрасно удалили из вопроса все ошибки и сообщение о самой ошибке! Как минимум получается, что у вас все в порядке, а какие-то придурки :) пишут об ошибках, которых вроде бы и нет. Вопрос должен оставаться исходным вопросом! Он может быть уточнен, но не изменен!

Comment: Вернул в исходной вариант. Буду знать!